# htaccess no-trailing-slash policy: non existing urls (404) should not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, trailing-slash

If I open a non existing url on my site like www.domain.de/abcde/ (with trailing slash) the url redirects to www.domain.de/abcde (without trailing slash) and opens the 404 site after.

But the 404 site should come directly when the url does not exist (without redirecting for the non-trailing-slash policy).

What do I need to add to my htaccess? Thank you!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

### ------

**starkeens suggestion** does only work on a clean htaccess, but I got some more code. It does not work together with the other lines. All the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect urls without www. to url with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301]

# hide the suffix of urls
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# start redirect everything to the subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
# except these folders: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vorschau [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
# end redirect everything to the subfolder

# no-trailing-slash policy
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Any new suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally i got a solution that seems to work..** maybe anyone got the same issue and needs the code. Comments for optimization are welcome!

```
# trailing Slashes

# to enforce a no-trailing-slash policy with subfolder
# is the request for a non-existent file?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if so, skip the next RewriteRule
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Now **only existing files** get the redirect of my no-trailing-slash policy. **Non existing files** aren't redirected and occur a 404 page directly, as wished.

Comment: this looks nice, but how to do the same thing but with a trailing slash policy?

Answer (score 1):

TRY :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: A blank site with the following error message opens, when trying to open a non existing url: 
"Not Found
The requested URL /abcde/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: **Thanks for your reply** I tested it on a clean htaccess and it worked (maybe except the root url, this got a slash all the time, I think). But it does not work with my other htaccess rules. I edited the question above and added the other rules. Maybe you got a new suggestion for me? Thx!